# Create playlist throws Nullpointerexception on Android 5.0

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, mediastore

Creating playlist using content resolver throws NullPointerException on Amazon devices running on android version 5.0.
It works fine on all other devices.

Class method that throw NPE:

```
public static long createPlaylist(final Context context,final String
    pname) {
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            ContentValues v1 = new ContentValues();
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            v1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, pname);
            v1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_MODIFIED,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());
            resolver.insert(uri, v1); // line 280 throws NPE
        ...
        ..
        .
   }
```

Here is stack trace(Thanks crashlytics)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1554)
android.content.ContentResolver.insert (ContentResolver.java:1207)
com.musicplayer.Utilities.createPlaylist (Utilities.java:280)
com.musicplayer.Utilities$3.onClick (Utilities.java:333)
android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage (AlertController.java:153)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:771)
```

Possible solution or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks before.

Comment: Probably `pname ` is `null`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i'm using default string like playlist 1, playlist 2,... there so it can't be null.

Comment: Simply attach debugger at `resolver.insert(uri, v1);` line and go inside to check which line causing issue by pressing STEP IN

Comment: i don't have that device(Amazon fire tablet) to create such a situation. it works fine on all other devices.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Amazon devices. I don't have a solution.. just wrapping it in a try-catch block and failing gracefully.